# Is the Intel C++ Compiler (19.0) now only using the Clang front-end (i.e. already abandoned EDG)?

Tags: c++, intel, icc, edg

In 16.0, the Intel C++ Compiler provided two compilers (one based on EDG, another based on Clang).

From the [16.0 documentation](https://software.intel.com/en-us/get-started-with-cpp-compiler-for-osx-parallel-studio-xe):

> **Using the Command Line**
>
> To invoke the compiler from the command line, use a command similar to
>   the following:
>
> - For C source files: `icc my_source_file.c` or `icl my_source_file.c`
> - For C++ source files: `icpc my_source_file.cpp` or `icl++
>     my_source_file.cpp`
>
> Following successful compilation, the compiler creates an executable
>   file in the current directory.
>
> `icl/icl++` is a Clang-based front-end. You can use Clang options with this compiler. `icc/icpc` is an EDG-based front-end. You cannot use Clang options with `icc/icpc`.

But I'm not seeing a similar description now.

Comment: Where are you seeing the "not similar" description now?

Comment: I see the latest 19.0 doc, https://software.intel.com/en-us/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference. And not find icl/icl++

Comment: @Zeson: You mean you cannot find icc/icpc?

Comment: @P.W I can not find icl and icl++. So I am not sure icc is clang-based frontend or EDG based now.

Answer (score 4):

If Intel is using **`icl/icl++`** to denote Clang-based front-end and **`icc/icpc`** to denote EDG-based front-end in 19.0 as well, then both these are available but on different platforms.

**`icc/icpc`** is available in Linux and macOS and **`icl`** is available in Windows.

From the [documentation](https://software.intel.com/en-us/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference-invoking-the-intel-compiler) of 19.0:

> **Linux***:
>
> Invoke the compiler using `icc/icpc` to compile `C/C++` source files.
>
> **macOS***:
>
> Invoke the compiler using `icc/icpc` to compile `C/C++` source files.
>
> **Windows***:
>
> You can invoke the Intel® C++ Compiler on the command line using the
>   **`icl`** command.

Comment: I don't think icl is clang-based flag, it's more like name convention of msvc, cl. So it's still not sure whether it's clang-based or EDG

Comment: "optimizing C (icc) and C++ (icpc) compiler" icc is C, not C++, like gcc vs g++ and clang vs clang++. And it is not clang based (ICC (Linux), ICL (Windows)), https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-C-Compiler/What-s-the-difference-between-icx-icl-and-icc-compilers/td-p/1224714

Comment: icl++/icl was also awailabe on MacOS. And it was clang based, but that is MacOS. https://web.archive.org/web/20150905074805/https://software.intel.com/en-us/get-started-with-cpp-compiler-for-osx-parallel-studio-xe

Answer (score 0):

In the current version for Linux, which is *Intel oneAPI Base Toolkit for Linux* 2021.1.8.1970, I could find `clang`, but neither `icc` nor `icpc`. So, just in case, I searched for `~/intel/oneapi/**/ic*(*)` with zsh (i.e. executable files starting with `ic`, recursively), and found `icx` and `icpx`. The output of `icx --help` says "Intel(R) C++ Compiler Help" and still mentions the executables `icc` and `icpc`, so the executables have apparently been renamed, but Intel forgot to update the documentation.

One can see both ICC and ICX mentioned on: https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/oneapi-c-compiler-system-requirements.html

Comment: ICC and ICPC does not come with the oneAPI base toolkit. It's provided with the HPC add-on. You can find them inside .intel64/ relative to  icx/icpx binary location. Source setvars.sh with 'intel64' argument to set the paths.